# Kali Linux sound problem

Tags: kali-linux, audio

I have a problem with Kali Linux that seems a bit odd: the sound works perfectly in the Google Chrome browser but when I try to play music or video on VLC or the other player that comes with Kali Linux The sound do not work!

- The sound used to be working just fine in both browser and media players.
- I've tried to play music while the browsers were closed and nothing happens.
- I have the same problem with all media files (mp4, mp3, wma, mkv. . .)
- I have launched vlc from the terminal and there was no error message.

  ```
  vlc '/root/Téléchargements/Son Lux - _Easy_ (Official Video).mp3'
  VLC media player 2.2.4 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.3-37-g888b7e89)
  [0000560055f800e8] core libvlc: Lancement de vlc avec l'interface par défaut. Utilisez « cvlc » pour démarrer VLC sans interface
  ```

  And when I close VLC:

  ```
  QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread.
  ```
- I updated the system but I'm not sure this is why the sound won't work. because I don't recall when this problem occurred.

Comment: Hmm, yes I see no error there. Next time, please run with `LC_ALL=C vlc /path/to/file` so the error messages can be in English. Also, why *in the world* are you running this as root!? Does it maybe work if you run as a regular user the way you're supposed to (I doubt it, but you never know)?

Comment: @terdon This is bizarre ! I have just created a new regular account and the sound works perfectly. Why ?

Comment: Great, please post that as an answer and [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it. That's just one more reason why you should *never* use root as your main account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)'s help I've found a solution (not so perfect by the way).

I have created a new regular user, because before I used root as my main account. And in this new session the sound works just fine !